# Returning a value from JSON Object

Tags: apex, json, parser

Hi I am trying to return a second value pair (string) from a JSON object using APEX's own built-in parser. The API query takes a string variable of a web domain.

However, I am getting a strange error I've never seen before:

```
Line: 7, Column: 0
expecting a semi-colon, found '<EOF>'
```

Here's my code:

```
 public class companyIDFetcher {

    public string companyIDFetcher (string domain){ 
        HTTPRequest companyIDRequest = new HTTPRequest();
        companyIDRequest.setEndpoint('https://api.api.com/api/v0/something/something/id?domain_name=' + domain);
        companyIDRequest.setMethod('GET');

        HTTP n = new HTTP();
        HTTPResponse companyIDResponse = n.send(companyIDRequest);
        string MosaicAPIBasicRequest = companyIDResponse.getBody();

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(MosaicAPIBasicRequest);
        parser.nextToken();
        parser.nextToken();
        parser.nextValue();
        String companyID = parser.getText();
        system.debug(companyID);
        return companyID;
    }
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Here's a JSON Response that I am receiving when making a http request:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "number_of_records": 3
  },
  "data": "13458245"
}
```

Comment: when are you getting the error? While compiling or while running the code?

Comment: are you running it in anonymous apex ? you have trash symbol before "public" access modifier word. Remove it.

Comment: I am getting the error while running the code.  Trash symbol removed. I am running in anonymous APEX.

Comment: Did you check the JSON request, since it might be possible there is no second pair and you have reached the object end. Can u also post the JSON response, which you receiving before parsing ?

Comment: anmrk: I just pasted the JSON response above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
Probably you need to change it with the correct field name

```
String response = '{"meta": {"number_of_records": 3},"data": "13458245"}';

JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response);
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if(parser.getCurrentName() == 'number_of_records') {
        parser.nextValue();
        System.debug(parser.getDecimalValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. in that case just check whether the json received is in correct format using json validator service found online. also only parse the response if the status code is 200

Comment: json validator service reports it as valid

Answer (score 0):

This kind of changes what you are doing, but have you used JSON.deserialize() before? (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm)

I prefer it as it allows you to separate a "Model" from your functionality. You could therefore do the following:

```
public class MosaicAPIBasicRequest {
    public Meta meta;
    public String data;

    public class Meta {
        public Integer number_of_records;
    }
}
```

With your original code changed to:

```
public class companyIDFetcher {

    public string companyIDFetcher (string domain){ 
        HTTPRequest companyIDRequest = new HTTPRequest();
        companyIDRequest.setEndpoint('....');
        companyIDRequest.setMethod('GET');

        HTTP n = new HTTP();
        HTTPResponse companyIDResponse = n.send(companyIDRequest);
        MosaicAPIBasicRequest request = (MosaicAPIBasicRequest) JSON.deserialize(companyIDResponse.getBody(), MosaicAPIBasicRequest.class);

        String companyID = request.data;
        system.debug(companyID);
        return companyID;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon but I am getting exactly the same error using this method... Line: 7, Column: 0
expecting a semi-colon, found '<EOF>'

Comment: I'm not sure then, it seems like the response is missing a closing bracket '}' or some other syntax character. I would guess that the error is in the JSON you are requesting.